# has_many belongs_to. Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have models:

```
Group(has_many students).
Student(belongs_to groups).
```

That's code of routes.rb

```
root 'courses#index'
  resources :students, :teachers, :groups, :courses, :users
```

That's code of def index and def group_params in GroupsController

```
def index
     @groups = Group.all
end

private
    def group_params
        params.require(:group).permit(:name, :course_id)
end
```

That's code of groups/index.html.erb

```
<% @groups.each do |g| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=link_to g.id, group_path(g)%></td>
            <td><%=link_to g.name, group_path(g)%></td>
            <td><%=link_to g.course.name, course_path(g)%></td>
            **<td><%=link_to g.students.name, student_path(g)%></td>**
<% end %>
```

I wrote two students in one group. How I can view names of all students of one group in index view? I try change to 
    g.student.name,

```
students_path(g), 

<%students.each do%>
   <td><%=link_to g.students.name, student_path(g)%></td>
<% end %>, 

resources :students do
    resources :groups
 end,

resources :groups do
    resources :students
 end
```

No one not working. 
Please help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**routes.rb**

```
resources :groups do
 resources :students
end
```

**groups/index.html.erb**

```
<% @groups.each do |g| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=link_to g.id, group_path(g)%></td>
        <td><%=link_to g.name, group_path(g)%></td>
        <td><%=link_to g.course.name, course_path(g)%></td>
        <% g.students.each do |student| %>
         <td><%=link_to student.name, student_path(g)%></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```